# Default not working in mongoose save - field is not saved

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema which includes the following defined field:

```
range: {type: Number, default: 100000, min: 1},
```

In the controller I set the range and save:

```
function postPlacard(req, res) {

    // Create a new instance of the Placard model
    var placard = new Placard();

    ...

    placard.range = req.body.range;

    ...

    placard.save(function(err) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json({ message: 'Placard added!', data: placard });
  });
}
```

The issue comes if I submit a POST with no range in the form.  In that case no range field is saved to the document.  This obviously means that range is less than its minimum of 1.

I would expect the range to be undefined before the save, and then during the save the default should be applied.

What is happening to cause the range to be missing from the saved document, and how could I correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're hitting this error because you're assigning to `placard.range` even when the `req.body.range` field is missing.  That overwrites the default `range` value set in `new Placard()`.

Qualify your assignment so that it only takes place if the field is present using something like:

```
if (req.body.range !== undefined) {
    placard.range = req.body.range;
}
```

Comment: What you suggest works, thanks.  From the 'why' perspective, this is (I think) a classic case of 'not defined'  vs 'undefined'.  By assigning an undefined vale to range, the mongoose default operation does not activate.  If range is 'not defined', the default activates.  It would be useful to have options as to when the default is applied e.g. it applies if variable is undefined. Otherwise we are effectively validating twice: once within our code and once with the mongoose validator.  I'll look into this further.